# Bloque begin-commit (Redshift) mal ejecutado en shell script

Tags: postgresql, shell

Tengo el siguiente script en shell que rescata las 200 tablas tablas con peores estadísticas, para aplicarles posteriormente un `analyze`:

```sh
echo `date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"`" - Comienza el proceso $job" >> $log_ejecucion
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------" >> $log_ejecucion

echo `date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"`" - Rescatamos las 200 tablas con mayor nivel de estadisticas malas" >> $log_ejecucion
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/ psql -h ${RSHOST} -p 5439 -U ${RSUID} ${RSDB} -t -A -c "select \"schema\",\"table\",stats_off,size from svv_table_info order by stats_off desc limit 200;" > /ruta1/tablas.tmp

echo `date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"`" - Abrimos el bloque de transaccion" >> $log_ejecucion
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/ psql -h ${RSHOST} -p 5439 -U ${RSUID} ${RSDB} -t -A -c "BEGIN;" >> $log_ejecucion

echo `date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"`" - Establecemos el threshold a 0" >> $log_ejecucion
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/ psql -h ${RSHOST} -p 5439 -U ${RSUID} ${RSDB} -t -A -c "set analyze_threshold_percent to 0;" >> $log_ejecucion

echo `date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"`" - Ejecutamos ANALYZE en cada una de ellas" >> $log_ejecucion
while read tabla
do
    SCHEMA=$(echo $tabla | cut -d "|" -f 1)
    TABLE=$(echo $tabla | cut -d "|" -f 2)
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/ psql -h ${RSHOST} -p 5439 -U ${RSUID} ${RSDB} -t -A -c "analyze $SCHEMA.$TABLE;" >> $log_ejecucion
done < /ruta1/tablas.tmp

echo `date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"`" - Cerramos el bloque" >> $log_ejecucion
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/ psql -h ${RSHOST} -p 5439 -U ${RSUID} ${RSDB} -t -A -c "COMMIT;"

echo `date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"`" - Fin del proceso $job - Elimino el fichero tablas.tmp" >> $log_ejecucion
rm -f /ruta1/tablas.tmp
echo "---------------Proceso terminado correctamente" >> /ruta1/analyze_200tablas_logfail.log
echo `date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"`" - Termina el proceso $job" >> $log_ejecucion
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------" >> $log_ejecucion
```

El problema es que para que Redshift haga correctamente el `analyze`, tengo que establecer el `analyze_threshold_percent` a 0. Como en la anterior versión del script, al revisar el log, siempre encontraba que había muchos `Analyze skip`, se me ocurrió meter el proceso dentro de un bloque `begin...commit`.

Aún así, sigue ejecutándose mal ya que en el log hay muchos `Analyze skip`, cosa que no debería ocurrir si ejecutase los doscientos analyze con el valor de analyze_threshold_percent correcto a 0.

Comment: No tengo experiencia con react ni psql, pero parece como si cada comando que ejecutas se ejecuta por separado y con conexión a la DB separada. Porque? No sera que el `set` no lo toma en cuenta antes del `COMMIT`?  No seria mas simple abrir _una_ conexión, y mandar todos los comandos a la vez?

Comment: He juntado tu comentario con tu respuesta y he realizado un fichero `.sql` que recoja el inicio del bloque, el set, todos los analyze y el commit, para lanzar en una sola conexión todas las sentencias.

Mañana revisaré el log para ver si ha funcionado correctamente.

Comment: @terdon He comprobado el log de ejecución y ha funcionado a las mil maravillas. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Marco tu respuesta como solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si funcionará bien ya que no tengo acceso a tu BD, pero quizas este version mas simple de tu script te ayudara:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo `date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"`" - Comienza el proceso $job" >> $log_ejecucion
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------" >> $log_ejecucion

echo `date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"`" - Rescatamos las 200 tablas con mayor nivel de estadisticas malas" >> $log_ejecucion


comandoSql=$(printf "BEGIN;\nset analyze_threshold_percent to 0;\n")
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/ psql -h ${RSHOST} -p 5439 -U ${RSUID} ${RSDB} -t -A -c "select \"schema\",\"table\",stats_off,size from svv_table_info order by stats_off desc limit 200;" |
  while read tabla
  do
    schema=$(echo "$tabla" | cut -d "|" -f 1)
    table=$(echo "$tabla" | cut -d "|" -f 2)
    comandoSql=$(printf "%s\n%s" "$comandoSql" "analyze $schema.$tabla;")
  done
comandoSql=$(printf "%s\n%s" "$comandoSql" "COMMIT;")
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/ psql -h ${RSHOST} -p 5439 -U ${RSUID} ${RSDB} -t -A -c "$comandoSql" >> $log_ejecucion

echo "---------------Proceso terminado correctamente" >> /ruta1/analyze_200tablas_logfail.log
echo `date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"`" - Termina el proceso $job" >> $log_ejecucion
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------" >> $log_ejecucion
```

Estoy pensando que el problema podria ser resuelto al ejecutar una sola lamada a la base.